# How to push code as different user?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

How to push code as different user?

I run:

```
git add .
git commit -m"Updated"
git push

Password for 'https://other_user@bitbucket.org':
```

I do not have the password for that user but I have access to this repository.

I need push as I do.

```
Password for 'https://my_account@bitbucket.org':
```

How to do it?

Comment: git itself does not support permissions for pushing or fetching. This is entirely responsibility of other protocols like `ssh` or `http/https`. You should ask [Bitbucket customer support](https://bitbucket.org/support) how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remote url associated with the branch you are trying to push is probably "https://other_user@bitbucket.org" and not "https://bitbucket.org".

You can check your remotes config using `git remote -v`.

You can either add a new remote (`git remote add new-remote-name url`) and push using `git push new-remote-name` or change existing url (`git remote set-url current-remote-name url`)

Comment: Bitbucket also allows you to easily view and copy your remote Git repository URL from your project page.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in the past by using format-patch/am.

Assuming that the change you want to massage is the tip of the current branch this should work (the `vim <patch_file_created>` is where you modify user name and email:

```
git format-patch -1
vim <patch_file_created>
git reset --hard HEAD~
git am <patch_file_created>
```